# Is there a particular form of the elements in $B[S]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a particular form of the elements in $B[S]$?

Let $A$ be a ring and $B$ a subring of $A$, $S$ a subset of $A$.

How are the elements of the set $B[S]=[B \cup S]$?

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, Is there a similiar construction for $B[S]$?

Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the construction of the polynomial ring, you should know that for all $n \ge 1$,
$$B[x_1, \dots , x_n] \subset A[x_1, \dots , x_n]$$
Obviously, for all $f \in B[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ and for all $s_1 , \dots , s_n \in S $ you have
$$f(s_1 , \dots , s_n) \in B[S]$$

Well, the subset of $A$ given by
$$\bigcup_{n \ge 1} \{ f(s_1 , \dots , s_n): s_1 , \dots , s_n \in S , f \in B[x_1, \dots , x_n] \}$$
forms a subring of $A$, hence it coincides with $B[S]$.

In the case where $S$ is a finite set with cardinality $m$, then you can simply consider $B[S]=\{ f(s_1 , \dots , s_m): s_1 , \dots , s_m \in S , f \in B[x_1, \dots , x_m] \}$.